# Combinatorial Probabilities

Tags: combinatorics

I've been trying out some of the early problems in the probabilistic method,
since I hear it can prove many problems in discrete mathematics. Let $A_1,...,
A_n$ be events such that the independent of all events except for at most $m$ of
them. Taking $0 < \epsilon < 1,$ and $Pr[A_i] \leq \frac{\epsilon}{n}(1-\frac{
\epsilon}{n})^m$ for $i = 1,...,n.$ I want to prove that $Pr[\cap_i\bar{A_i}\geq
1-\epsilon.$ Here's what I have going so far:
$$Pr[\cap_i \bar{A_i}] = 1 - Pr[\bar{\cap_i \bar{A_i}}] = 1 - Pr[\cup_i A_i],$$
which from here becomes an inclusion-exclusion problem that I am having issues
trying to combinatorially count. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to worry about Inclusion-Exclusion here. The proof is much simpler.

By [Boole's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality), we have: $$\Pr\left[\displaystyle\bigcup_{i = 1}^{n}A_i\right] \le \displaystyle\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\Pr[A_i] \le \displaystyle\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\dfrac{\epsilon}{n}\left(1-\dfrac{\epsilon}{n}\right)^m = \epsilon\left(1-\dfrac{\epsilon}{n}\right)^m \le \epsilon.$$

Therefore, $$\Pr\left[\displaystyle\bigcap_{i = 1}^{n}\bar{A}_i\right] = 1-\Pr\left[\displaystyle\bigcup_{i = 1}^{n}A_i\right] \ge 1-\epsilon.$$